# Best practice to DELETE multiple rows from my SQLite table

Tags: sqlite, sql-insert, sql-delete

I have a table called `fingerprints`. Every minute a new row is inserted. There are more tables: `metadata`, `locations` etc. where there is `fingerprint_ID` defined as `foreging_key`. These tables are huge, they receive about 200-300 new rows per minute, so at the end of the day there is a large amount of new data.

Once a day, I delete all unused rows from the fingerprints table and "on delete cascade" the data from the other tables. This action can take about 2 minutes:

```
DELETE FROM fingerprints WHERE date < '2023-10-25 00:00:00:00' and used = false;
```

My DB gets locked for around 2 minutes and all `INSERT` statements that were to be performed in that time are left waiting. The problem is that my process needs to continuously have recent data otherwise it **fails**.

Could someone help me with this problem? What would be the best practice to delete unnecessary rows when there is new data being inserted?

Comment: Hi. You can use [`TRIGGER`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) for solve this.

Comment: Do you have an index on `(date, used)`? Without such index the `where` probably needs to search through all the rows and escalate the lock to table level.

Comment: Hi @jurez if I change that query by this one: 
`DELETE FROM fingerprints WHERE id  < 10908;`
I will have the same problem. The problem is not in the main table searching because there are not to many rows... The problem is on the child tables, there are a lot of rows that have to be deleted "On delete cascade".

Comment: You need appropriate indexes on those tables too.